# AMD gpu pro Error installation Ubuntu 20.04 AMD RX580

Tags: drivers, software-installation, amd-graphics, gpu

When i try to install amd drivers always returs me error

ERROR: This package can only be installed on Ubuntu 18.04.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-pin (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-pro-pin package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 1

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

ERROR: Unable to install amdgpu-pro-pin.
This driver may not support the running operating system.

i know the drivers are for ubuntu 18.04 but in amd website they dont have any others .... if someone can help ?  Many Tnx!